# In openssl cipher suites, does AES128 imply AES128-CBC if another mode is not explicitly mentioned?

Tags: tls, cryptography, openssl

For example (from `openssl ciphers -v`), for AES128, the output:

`AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA Au=RSA Enc=AES(128) Mac=SHA256`

is given. Does `Enc=AES(128)` imply `AES(128)-CBC`? I am inclined to believe so as no mode is mentioned and the output from `openssl list-cipher-algorithms` shows `AES128 => AES-128-CBC`.

Comment: This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403803/openssl-modes-of-operation-in-cipher-suites) - you can get the modes of operation on the [openssl man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/ciphers.html#CIPHER-SUITE-NAMES)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The OpenSSL names are slightly different to the standard names. The man page here has the mapping:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/apps/ciphers.html

In particular see this:

```
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA            AES128-SHA
```

So the OpenSSL name `AES128-SHA` corresponds to the standard ciphersuite using RSA and AES-128 in CBC mode.